# startActivityForResult Null pointer exception. Context?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

At the risk of winning StackOverloads "Dumbass of the Year Award" I'm still having problems with this (sigh). My other posts on this have been:

- [Null Pointer Exception using Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124006/null-pointer-exception-using-intent)
- [NullPointerException in SharedPreferences Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991289/sharedpreferences-null-pointer-exception)
- [How to route the user to the correct activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939591/how-to-route-the-user-to-the-correct-activity)

The call comes from a submenu:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        pob = new Prefs();// public Prefs pob; in field vars
    switch (item.getItemId()){
//-------------------------------------Options menu----------------------------------------
    case R.id.about:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "About menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //showAbout();  
        return true;
    case R.id.locale:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Locale menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

//-----Sub menu----------
    case R.id.uk_item://<-- USING THIS BLOCK FOR CALL
    Toast.makeText(this, "UK selected in UsFM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// this is ok
        Log.i(LogTag, "UK selected");
        if(pob.isUk&&item.isChecked()){
            item.setChecked(true);
        }else item.setChecked(false);
        pob.changeLocale(this,"uk");
        //finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.us_item:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "US already selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(pob.isUs&&item.isChecked()){
            item.setChecked(true);
        }
        else item.setChecked(false);
        pob.setRegion("us");
        pob.getRegion(this);
        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.eu_item:
        Toast.makeText(this, "EU selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(pob.isEu&&item.isChecked()){
            item.setChecked(true);
//          pob.changeLocale("eu");
        }else item.setChecked(false);
        return true;
    default :
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

It calls this method in the Prefs class:

```
public void changeLocale(Context cxt,String locale){
    try{
    String l=locale;
     if(l.equals("uk")){
        this.isUk=true;
        Log.i(Log_tag,l);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "UK region selected in Prefs",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(cxt, Uk.class);
        Log.i(Log_tag,"intent run");
        startActivity(intent);// <--- ERROR HERE
    }else if(l.equals("eu")){
        this.isEu=true;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "EU region selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(cxt, Eu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(l.equals("us")){
        this.isUs=true;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Us region selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(cxt, Us.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (l.equals("")){
        Log.i(Log_tag,"no locale passed in");
        finish();
    }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(Log_tag, "Null Pointer Error in changeLocale()"+e);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
05-26 13:53:05.880: WARN/System.err(478): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 13:53:05.890: WARN/System.err(478):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2661)
05-26 13:53:05.900: WARN/System.err(478):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2705)
05-26 13:53:05.900: WARN/System.err(478):     at com.silifeform.android.Prefs.changeLocale(Prefs.java:70)
05-26 13:53:05.900: WARN/System.err(478):     at       com.silifeform.android.Us.onOptionsItemSelected(UsFuelMoney.java:347)
05-26 13:53:05.910: WARN/System.err(478):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2096)
05-26 13:53:05.910: WARN/System.err(478):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:825)
05-26 13:53:05.920: WARN/System.err(478):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
```

05-26 13:53:05.920: WARN/System.err(478):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:813)
05-26 13:53:05.920: WARN/System.err(478):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:120)

Stephan very kindly made some suggestions regarding instantiating the prefs object in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, but as I am new to both android and java I don't know any other ways to instantiate an object other than the two I have already tried.

Sorry if I'm asking the same question over and over again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Eu.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If that bit gives a nullpointer, that means either the context/this is empty or the Eu.class is empty. Try to walk trough it with the debug mode to check if either of both has a null value. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nallath, thats causing the error to occur on the Intent intent line. I don't understand how to ensure how "this" or Eu.class is not empty. Are they not automatically given a context as part of extending Activity?

Comment: "this" is keyword that is a pointer to the activity or view the code is called from. The Eu.class shouldn't be empty either, so my guess is that the cxt (context) you are putting in the Intent is empty or not what the Intent needs to function. How is the context set? (Where does it get the context from?)
You could always try: Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

Comment: I think the context is set in the submenu call:case R.id.uk_item://<-- USING THIS BLOCK FOR CALL    Toast.makeText(this, "UK selected in UsFM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// this is ok        Log.i(LogTag, "UK selected");        if(pob.isUk&&item.isChecked()){            item.setChecked(true);        }else item.setChecked(false);        pob.changeLocale(this,"uk");        //finish();        return true;

Comment: sorry thats not clear. In the first area of code above, theres the line pob.changeLocale(this,"uk"); Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
I personally never use context to create an Intent and my guess is that is what is causing the problem

Comment: I think thats helped. Ive put an intent in the US class to move to the prefs class, which should then go to the uk, but its still opening the US activity. I'm not getting a NPE error anymore though :)

Comment: In my case it was because of I'd used startActivity inside doInBackground method of a AsyncTask class,moving startActivity to the onPost function solved the problem